# How to handle multiple canvas and async behaviour?

Tags: p5.js

I was doing some multiple canvas practice: I'm trying to paint pixels of one canvas to another, but the thing is when I load an image in first canvas I don't know how to wait for it in second canvas.

```js
function sketch(p) {

  p.preload = function() {
    p.img = p.loadImage('/*...*/')
  }

  p.setup = function() {
    //...
  };
}

var myp = new p5(sketch);

function sketch2(p) {
  p.setup = function() {
    myp.loadPixels(); // this is not giving anything
    // but works when myp doesnt have a preload    
  };
}

var main = new p5(sketch2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `preload()` function handles asynchronous loading within its instance so it halts the execution of the `setup()` of *only* the first sketch. The problem is that there are two instances so you end up trying to call `loadPixels()` when there aren't any pixels to load yet.

When you get rid of the preload, the creation of the first sketch happens fast enough that there will be something to load when `loadPixels()` is used. It can be done elegantly but, to illustrate the point, you could move the `var main = new p5(sketch2);` line to be executed at the end of the setup of the first sketch and see it working:

```
function sketch(p) {
    p.preload = function() {
        p.img = p.loadImage('https://picsum.photos/200');
    }

    p.setup = function() {

        //Something to display and check that the pixels are actually loaded.
        //Can be ignored.
        //p.createCanvas(200, 200);
        //p.background(0);
        //p.image(p.img, 0, 0);

        var main = new p5(sketch2);
    }
}

var myp = new p5(sketch);

function sketch2(p) {
    p.setup = function() {
        myp.loadPixels()
        console.log(myp.pixels); 

        p.createCanvas(200, 200);
        p.background(125);
    };
}
```